# ng-minlength in directive not populated when invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating an input directive that encapsulates a label, and some error messaging but I'm getting stuck with ng-minlength and ng-maxlength. The issue is that they don't populate the model value until it's a valid value, so my parent scope can display a value while my directive doesn't, and vice versa. View this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KgN4qtWi7lRwrPG2UgH4?p=preview) for an example of what I mean.

Is the only way around this to define my own minlength and maxlength validators? Is there some way configure this behaviour so the model is always populated? I want to use all the built in validators in my directive, so no doubt this will be an issue with all of them and I'd rather not redefine them all.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller"> 
    <label>Outer scope 1</label>
    <input name="input1" type="text" ng-model="model1" ng-minlength="4"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Directive scope 1</label>
    <input-dir ng-model="model1" ng-minlength="0"></input-dir>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label>Outer scope 2</label>
    <input name="input3" type="text" ng-model="model2"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Directive scope 2</label>
    <input-dir ng-model="model2" ng-minlength="4"></input-dir>


  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope){
  $scope.model1 = "Model1";
  $scope.model2 = "Model2";
});

app.directive('inputDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-minlength="{{ minlength }}" />',
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      minlength: '=ngMinlength'
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I guess that the viewvalue is only passed to the model when it is in a valid state

Comment: Yeah, does anyone have any other suggestions for this, other than implementing my own validators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issue, I solved this by redefining all the validators, except now they return the value when invalid so the model is populated. Just include the valuedValidators module. These validators are available on the $error object as vvminlength etc.

**vv-validators.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var validators = {};
    validators.vvUrl = function(value){
        var urlRegex = new RegExp(/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi);
        return urlRegex.test(value);
    }

    validators.vvEmail = function(value){
        var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
        return emailRegex.test(value);
    }

    validators.vvMinlength = function(value, min){
        var huh = value.length >= parseInt(min);
        return min && value && huh;
    }

    validators.vvMaxlength = function(value, max){
        return max && value && value.length <= parseInt(max);
    }

    validators.vvMin = function (value, min) {
        return min && parseFloat(value) >= parseFloat(min);
    }

    validators.vvMax = function (value, max) {
        return max && parseFloat(value) <= parseFloat(max);
    }

    validators.vvPattern = function (value, pattern) {
        return pattern && new RegExp(pattern).test(value);
    }

    validators.vvFloat = function (value) {
        var floatRegex = new RegExp(/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/);
        return floatRegex.test(value);
    }

    validators.vvInteger = function (value) {
        var integerRegex = new RegExp(/^\-?\d+$/);
        return integerRegex.test(value);
    }

    var app = angular.module('valuedValidators', []);

    var names = Object.keys(validators);
    names.forEach(function(name){
        app.directive(name, function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                    controller.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                        var valid = true;
                        var attrValue = attrs[name];
                        var func = validators[name];
                        if (attrValue !== 'false') {
                            valid = func(viewValue, attrValue);
                            controller.$setValidity(name.toLowerCase(), valid);
                        }
                        return viewValue;
                    });
                }
            };
        });
    });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Could you post an example of how you're using this now with your directive? I am similarly trying to encapsulate a label, input field, and validation messages within a directive and because Angular stresses validation at the template level rather than at the controller or model level, I'm having a tough time figuring out how to pass in the validation criteria for a specific field into my directive so that it will "flow through" to the input field itself...

Comment: Hey Alex, you need to specify your ngModel as '=' in your directives scope so that the inner input is two way bound to the value on the outer scope. You must also ensure your models are properties on objects, or you'll lose the references to them in the inner scope once they're modified. If you use the controller as syntax, you get this behaviour by default.

I've added my directive definition and the template and usage to this Plunk. It won't work, cos it relies on other code I haven't posted, but hopefully it helps.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KuHmtktjv0dPgyV8cpb7?p=preview

Comment: Simon, thanks for the Plunk. It does help visualize your approach. Ideally I could specify validation properties on the model or controller and bind to an error property for each form field. The problem is that I need to have a custom message for each validation on each field, and may not be able to have it as generic as you have supplied buried into the directive. I am newer to Angular but have a lot of Ember experience. I used this mixin with Ember to accomplish this and it worked swimmingly: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations

Comment: Hey Alex, if you look at the directive definition I have there, you'll see you can specify customs msgs for each validator. eg vv-minlength-msg="Custom". The setup in the compile() function is just to define some default msging in case none is supplied. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you post some code in a Plunk, I could take a look at it. Perhaps in a new question?

Answer (score 0):

There is an even easier solution: use two textareas.

The first serves as a draft, the second is the model where the verification is to take place.

```
<textarea name="message_body_draft" cols="47" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"
    ng-model="message_body_draft"
    ng-change="message_body=message_body_draft"></textarea>

<textarea name="message_body" style="width: 100%;" disabled ng-model="message_body"
    ng-minlength="100" required></textarea>
```

When the user writes in the first one, it automatically will populates the right model (the second one).